# how can i get a same result gpio.input at nodejs?

Tags: node.js, iot, gpio

I figured out that gpio.input & gpio.output are only supported in py.
 How can I get a same result in nodejs?
read only return 0,1 which is useless in photocell sensor in raspberry pi.

Answer (score 1):

you might have a look at this node module package : [rpi-gpio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpi-gpio).

But unfortunatly for you, the only value you will receive from this input will be either 0 or 1 because you can not perform analog  reading on GPIO on RPi.
A solution is to buy a little module which can read analog and then write it in a serial communication to read it with RPi.

If you don't want to buy that kind of module there is a tricks which use a capacitor and then computes the time between two ones to know the value between 0 and 1024 for example. This article explains that well : [capacitor analog](https://fr.scribd.com/document/193892647/RaspberryPi-Analogue-Input-with-Capacitor-node-js)